# How to extract list from an Index output from pandas?

Tags: python, list, pandas, csv, indexing

I want to read the columns(a, b and c) of a csv file. I am using the below code to do so:-

```
tt=pd.read_csv('abc.csv', nrows=1,sep='|').columns
```

The output is an Index as shown below.

```
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

How do I extract the list ['a','b','c'] from the above index. Is there any other more elegant way to read column header of a csv file to a list without loading the whole csv file?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('abc.csv', nrows=1,sep='|').columns.tolist()`

Comment: Seriously:) Thanks it worked.

Comment: You could've just done `list(tt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. The tolist function is useful to translate the index into list

```
> import pandas as pd 
> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':['a','b','c']})    
> df.columns.tolist()
```